# Access external directories from symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have images that are stored in a directory in /var/lib/myproject. So they are outside of my symfony project. I would like to display them in a twig template or via css.

How could I access them as symfony is catching every url and rewrites them?

Setting a specific route doesn't work :

```
my_project_res:
    resource: "/var/lib/myproject"
    prefix:   /res
```

Comment: "theme" or "them"? forget it! let's discuss your question..why not put images in your project? really need to be placed outside of the project?

Comment: "them" thanks :). Yes they are externalized because they are resources that are not directly dependant of the application.

Comment: Can't you just set a relative path like "../../../../../var/lib/myproject/" ?

Comment: "../../../../../var/lib/myproject/" doesn't work. However, wouldn't it be a huge security issue if it worked?

Comment: Why not symlink the whole directory into your project's web path and let the web server handle these files? This seems like the best way here, so that Symfony doesn't have to handle such things.

Comment: Hi kix, this is actually what I think I will do if there is no symfony solution, which seems to be the case...

Comment: You can use a bundles like `https://github.com/igorw/IgorwFileServeBundle` to serve files from outside of the web directory.